# Can I implement google maps and Mapbox together?

Tags: google-maps, mapbox

I want accuracy of google map for searching places in map and free usage of directions that is provided by mapbox if I am wrong then please respond

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Mapbox Terms of Service](https://www.mapbox.com/legal/tos) cover all relevant details about how Mapbox products can be used with third party data. The [Google Maps APIs Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms-20180207) cover similar details for Google implementations. I'd recommend reading through both references in detail to understand how the limitations will apply to your specific implementation.